# Losing connection to sql server 2008 in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, debugging, sqlconnection

I use the `SqlConnection` class to connect to the server and after some time and some queries, I get the very common

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server).

The problem is that I can connect to the server and I only get the error after sometime and after running some queries, while this is a classic cannot connect at all error...

Why is this happening? What can possible cause such behavior?

Any help/direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using one connection, or are you disposing - recreating?

Comment: Can you provide code detail of how you are calling SQLConnection and how you are closing the connection. Can you also provide details of what queries you manage to run and after which query (or is it abbrubtly) this error occurs.

Comment: Check in the windows event logs for any SQL related job is failing. SQL server transaction log might be another area to look at. Code will be quite helpful to answer.

Comment: Is the code running on a different machine then the db-server? Because it migth be, that there is a network problem, and you really can't connect to the server at that time.

Comment: Anri I am disposing - recreating

Comment: András Ottó the code is running on a different machine than the db-server, but I don't have any connection problems in other programs. It happens in debug mode and after it happens, I can't connect for some minutes. The time after which it occurs and the time it needs to connect again are pretty random. Btw I am using integrated security.

Comment: @user1910236 ok, let's assume you are disposing connections properly. Are there any other clients? Can it be connections limit is reached from time to time? Have you tried to look into Sql Server log?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with connection pooling. Check the lifecycle of sql connection object.

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs while you are debugging your application, it's perfectly normal.

After you are checking the code and move on to the next query execution, while the connection is still not closed in your code, it actually times out.

Comment: Yea it happens in debug mode, but I don't get the reason, since it should be using a connection pool. If that is the problem, what should I do? Should I keep the connection open?

Comment: Just increase your connection timeout for debugging purposes. You may want to look at [#IF ... #ENDIF Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyscbeay(v=vs.80).aspx), so you could conditionally use a different connection timeout depending on your scenario (debugging or not).

Answer (score -2):

Check keep-alive timeout and advance it accordingly at your SQL server connection parameters. SQL server drops connections with no activity after short down-time inactivity timer